# Steps for redesigning an iPad app for Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, ipad, macos, user-interface

What commonly expected user-visible design idioms need to change from an iPad app to a Mac app for an app, that is to provide basically identical functionality, to seem at least reasonably Mac OS X native?

Some of these changes, commonly expected by users, might include:

1. Move the Settings button and Info button to Menu selections for Preferences... and About...
2. Move the Settings view and Info view or popover to their own independent Preferences and About windows instead of being views in the main window.
3. Add some menu items and menu keys for commonly used buttons (like the forward and back buttons in a browser).
4. Support arrow keys for scrolling any custom view items.
5. Support mouse-over for help popups or dynamic menus.
6. If the app supports "documents", allow more than one document to be open at a time, each in their own windows.

What else?  What's the minimum change required for a simple generic 2D game?

Added clarifications:

Note that I do not consider re-coding similar UI classes to NS classes (for instance UIButtons to NSButtons), with similar look, positions and behaviors, to be a significant change.  Those changes are pretty much invisible to the user.

The goal is to change as little as possible so that a user who purchased app X to do Y on an iPad might purchase app X to do Y on their Mac, as a Mac application, but with as close to zero learning curve as possible.  But it seems that some changes need to be made, or the app would not seem to be a Mac app (for instance, a missing About... menu item would seem a bit strange.)

Comment: You should really rewrite the app for mac.  The mac and iPad are different in almost every way... your apps should be too.

Comment: So what would change in a rewrite?

Comment: I hate to be negative but this is a silly question and as stated is unanswerable.  Apple has a very large user interface standards guide, read that.

Comment: @ditkin : The complete HIG may or may not be relevant, given the current popularity of quick iPad ports and other non-compliant apps (some say including Apple's) in the Mac App store.  The market speaks.

Comment: @hotpaw2 that I agree with.  Apple is not afraid to innovate in violation of their own guidelines.  But that does not make this question any easier to answer :)

Comment: _So what would change in a rewrite?_
Everything.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy - The goal is the opposite: to change nothing in the Mac version, unless not changing a feature would be quite disconcerting even to a heavy user of the iPad version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

> to provide basically identical
>   functionality, to seem at least
>   reasonably Mac OS X native?

You've gone off the rails right there. Consider adding this to your list:

1. **Forget everything you know about how your iPad app works.** Step back and consider that a user's interaction with and expectation of a desktop application are very different from those of a tablet. Re-think what you're able to do and what the user will want to do with a faster processor, more power, significantly more available storage, less mobility, much faster text entry, and a different user interface model.

Comment: The game or app doesn't even use a large fraction of the full capability of an iPad.  So the extra power of a Mac buys nothing, given that I want the game or app to seem pretty much identical for marketing reasons, if nothing else.  (e.g. marketing says: No new features.  But make it a Mac app.)

Comment: @hotpaw2 Sorry, I missed the line about it being a game. Games are a somewhat different situation -- they don't produce anything, and there's much more UI flexibility. But what I said stands: consider the differences in how the user interacts and what they can do before you do anything else. A desktop user will probably be running other applications at the same time, no multi-touch interface (in most cases), screen larger but farther away, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We are in the same boat and faced the same question.

Our conclusion is to start with a "fresh" real application for Mac and make it look similar, i.e. using the same or similar UI components and graphics. The app should be otherwise developed as if there was no iPad version.

First, there will be many users that *don't* have the iPad version. Those users expect a full-blown Mac application and it doesn't make sense to make it feel iPad in any way.

Second, users coming from the iPad version will feel ripped of if the Mac app is just a pure clone of the iPad version with no added value. Think of the first transitions from iPhone to iPad - paying again for nothing but pure upscales is frustrating and might harm your business in the long run.

Starting out designing a fresh streamlined UI and then think of what you can reuse and make similar. Functionality may differ in one direction or the other. Your model code should work in all places anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but take a look at [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/). It's essentially a port of `UIKit` to the Mac. It was created by The Icon Factory to make it easy for developers to port their iOS apps to the Mac. IIRC Twitterific was ported to the Mac using Chameleon.

Comment: Thanks.  I have looked at Chameleon.  But it isn't finished, and I'd already translated many of my UI class objects to NS class objects, pretty much 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I did to create a Mac app from an iPad app, and have it accepted into the Mac App store.

- Ignored the suggestions to completely redesign the app (users reasonably liked the iPad design).
- Create a Mac app project and include a branch of all the iOS source code.
- Manually recode all the UI elements with their corresponding NS elements.  Resize them to Mac UI guideline sizes.  Check that they all show up in some reasonable place when the  main window is resized.  Deleted iPad only delegates, such as rotation handlers, etc.  This resulted in completely new view controller code, but almost all the code was just a parallel translation of the other paradigm.
- Set the view coordinates to flipped so the Y coordinates won't have to be recalculated for any Core Graphics drawing routines.  (The Model and CG drawing code pretty much ported straight over without change, except for scale factors for window size, and such.)
- Remove settings and help views from the main window view controller(s).  Implement a Preferences window xib and a Help window xib, and put all the settings and pref views and controls there.  Add one more top level controller to show/hide the 3 windows.
- Add some menu selections with hotkeys for equivalent UIButton actions that a user might want to hit without reaching for the mouse/trackpad.
- Add a credits.html file.
- Add an outline shape and transparency masks to the icon design, and stuff into an .icns file.
- Pad the one window screen shot out to the much larger required size.